# All data lost when pushing new version to AWS using elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having a really annoying problem when deploying my Rails app to AWS using elastic beanstalk. Everytime I made some changes to my production code and did "git aws.push", all previous data in my RDS instance would be lost. I tried many things, like creating the database from a snapshot, but it doesn't seem to work...Can anyone who has experience give me some tips? That would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you have a file called <application_name>.config under .ebextensions? It seems like your file is calling a rake task to reload the database instance. I have had the same issue before - check out how to make sure the database is recovered from a snapshot here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428715/how-to-restore-database-in-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using existing RDS database with your Elastic Beanstalk application, then it could be that your associated RDS database was created with the default deletion policy - "Delete".

There's a note on Elastic Beanstalk RDS DB creation page:

> Your RDS DB Instance will be deleted if you terminate the environment.
>   Create a snapshot to save your data.

"Create Snapshot" is another option for deletion policy.

Since Elastic Beanstalk environment is terminated on each deployment, it might be the case for your RDS database data loss on each git push.

Comment: FWIW - git aws.push does not terminate your database/environment. It simply pushes new code and deploys it. eb stop terminates your environment and is when data loss is possible.