# How to restore database in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8 on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. After several issues with my side of the data, I did a rake db:reload

Now I am trying to grab the data that I had already created in the database pre-reload. I have followed the instructions in the Amazon documentation .

However, on step 6: Type the name of the restored DB instance in the DB Instance Identifier text box. - The prompt forces to give a new name to the Instance - thus creating a new instance.

That is all good, except I cannot change the db instance I am using with Elastic Beanstalk, so it seams useless to me. Unless I am missing something.

Help, please!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After pouring over the interwebs for several days - I tried something that works!

Let's say the corrupted instance is called "badinstance". It has an endpoint called: badinstance.c5taqjjaja1d.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

Once you have restored the database to point in time, RDS will create a new instance, let's say you called it "newinstance".

Your Elastic Beanstalk will still be pointing to badinstance.c5taqjjaja1d.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 
First delete "badinstance" - scary I know - I did multiple backups before I actually hit "delete. 
Then click on "newinstance" and select modify. You will be able to change the instance identifier to "badinstance". Make sure at this point that the security groups on the db instance match the group you have to Elastic Beanstalk.

The name changing took a long time to take place (I made the request around 3 pm or so and saw that it went through at around 3:50 am the next morning).

I restarted the Elastic Beanstalk app-server and voila: the data had been restored.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone down the road.

Sam

Comment: I followed this answer, and it works!! But instead of deleting the older DB I just renamed it by appending the "-old" prefix. CAUTION AHEAD!

Note that: If you rename it, all the snapshots will go away, because as of now, the AWS console UI shows snapshots if the name matches. Therefore, restore the DB first using a snapshot before deleting or renaming the older DB instance.

Answer (score 2):

@Samanta

Modifying db instance is applied by default in the next maintenance window defines, you can check "Apply immediately" in the modify screen to get changes applied now.

Comment: I did not see that option - next time I run into this issue, I will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: 4.5 years later, can confirm the "Apply immediately" option is there and works :)