# Restoring an Elastic Beanstalk RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

When rebuilding an elastic beanstalk environment, EB automatically recreates a new and associated RDS instance.

Once associated, RDS instances cannot be dissociated from an EB environment.

I have a snapshot of the previous RDS prior to the rebuild.

You cannot restore RDS snapshots to an existing RDS instance.

How then, can I rebuild the environment with my desired snapshot attached? Or, how can I use my existing snapshot, or how can I migrate the existing snapshot data to the new database (I tried a data export with create schema's but lacked permissions on the import). Any appropriate but ideally simple option will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore database in Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428715/how-to-restore-database-in-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a snapshot of your RDS DB, you can create a new environment with it. For this, you need to specify the [`DBSnapshotIdentifier`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-rdsdbinstance) option setting.

1. Create a file `.ebextensions/rds_builder.config` in the root of your project
2. Add the following:

   ```
   option_settings:
     aws:rds:dbinstance:
       DBSnapshotIdentifier: <snapshot ID here>
   ```

**EDIT:**

You can also create a new environment using a [saved configuration template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-savedconfig.html) of the present one. It is likely that this saved template will contain information in the `aws:rds:dbinstance` (since you have associated your present environment with an RDS), so you would need to basically modify this bit to point to your snapshot. This should work, and is probably the better approach.

Comment: Is it trivial to 'create a new environment' from an existing one? How does that differ from a rebuild? Your answer looks like something I'll refer back to but it is not immediately useful because I lack context. I went with https://stackoverflow.com/a/19483247/4682556

Comment: With the application code (which also contains the above-mentioned `.ebextension` to specify the snapshot ID), I would just create a new environment.

You can also create a new environment using a saved configuration template of the present one. It is likely that this saved template will contain information in the `aws:rds:dbinstance` (since you have associated your present environment with an RDS), so you would need to basically modify this bit to point to your snapshot. This should work, and is probably the better approach, but I have never tried it.

Comment: Check this out: [Using Elastic Beanstalk Saved Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-savedconfig.html)

Comment: is there a way to do it without the code project? i can only manage it through the aws web console...